# apache client authentication - set fingerprint of client certificate as header value

Tags: apache, ssl, authentication

i have a working ssl client authentication setup. is there a way to get the client certs fingerprint and put it in the request header when forwarding the request to another app?

according to:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html

there is nothing like:

```
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_X_FINGERPRINT "%{SSL_CLIENT_X_FINGERPRINT}s"
```

any help appreciated

marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is to pass the whole certificate (`SSL_CLIENT_CERT`) and compute the fingerprint once it gets to your application.

Depending on how it's implemented, this shouldn't be too hard to do. For example, you could implement a `Filter` to do it in a Java servlet environment if needed: decode the PEM-encoded certificate to get it in DER form, pass the byte[] array you get to a `MessageDigest` initialised with the algorithm you require (and possibly hex-encode the result).

Note that "fingerprint" is a rather loose word. Most tools would use SHA-1 nowadays, but this hasn't necessarily always been the case (and this could change).

As a side-note, what you're trying to do suggests you're not using traditional PKI for authentication, but accepting potential self-signed certificates (or certificates signed by unknown CAs) and compare those fingerprints against a list you know. If this is the case, you're probably not interested so much in the "X.509 certificate" aspect of all this, but you're only using this certificate as a public key container (for which SSL/TLS would guarantee you the client has the matching private key), therefore you might find it more flexible to compare public keys, rather than certificates.

Comment: hi, bruno. thanks for your answer. you are right. we have created our own CA and want some clients to connect to our server (with the certs we have signed). after the handshake is done it should be sufficient to the the clients DN and compare it to the list of known clients. we only want to be able to find out about the connecting client and let apache deal with the ssl termination.

Comment: That's different then, if you have your own CA, you can indeed use it as a normal PKI and use the Subject DN directly. It's probably best in this case to accept only certificates from your CA (or a restricted number of CAs you trust) in the Apache Httpd config.